# Using "http" causes segmentation fault in gethostbyname()

Tags: c, networking, gethostbyname

This is a weird problem. When I use gethostbyname() in the following example, it works:

```
struct hostent *info = gethostbyname("www.youtube.com"); 
printf("Host: %s\n",info->h_name);
```

But when I use it with the following, it fails to work:

```
struct hostent *info = gethostbyname("http://www.youtube.com"); 
printf("Host: %s\n",info->h_name);
```

Upon using the above method, I try to access the `h_name` which is a part of the `hostent` struct. That causes a segmentation fault. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Why not just sanitize the input to be sure you're using a host name, not a fully-qualified URL?

Comment: @EdCottrell Could you elaborate further on what you mean? I'm brand new to C networking (and low level networking programming in general).

Comment: The `http` is the protocol, not part of the host name. The `www` is the host name, `youtube.com` is the domain name, and `www.youtube.com` is the FQDN.

Comment: What @RonMaupin said. Don't include the `http://`. The error occurs because `gethostbyname` fails and so `info->h_name` is a memory violation.

Comment: `gethostbyname` returns zero pointer if it is unable to find host. You have to check function result before using it.

Comment: OK. So the user gives me a URL like this: "http://www.domain.com/something.html" (with the http://) What is the best way to remove the "http://" and everything after the "/" ?

Comment: You can do it manually, use strstr for instance to search for "://" and then if that exists, skip that part of the string. Then search for the first "/" and then you can for instance replace that character with the '\0' character.